# Gmail client renders '&nbsp;' as symbol in preview

Tags: html, css, gmail

The Gmail client renders `&nbsp;` as symbol not as a white-space in preview:

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center" width="560">Content</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Your missing semicolons `;` at the end of your `&nbsp` is this a typo in your question or the source of your bug?

Comment: sorry this is my mistake. there is semicolons in my code;

Comment: You should edit your code. I will do this for you this time. How are you adding the code to Gmail? Did you already used the browser developers tools that the intended HTML code is added instead of something else?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `text-decoration:none`

```html
<td style="text-decoration:none;">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center" width="560">Content</td>
<td style="text-decoration:none;">&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: @D-lemma did you include your html in <body>?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use padding or margin instead of non breaking space.

```
  <td align="center" width="560" border="1" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">Content</td>
```

Comment: Try to remove the <td>&nbsp;</td> and just try to use one <td align="center" width="560">Content</td> only. @D-lemma

Comment: Answer has been update. Try the following codes above.

Comment: doesnt help =(((